# How to join a Microsoft Workgroup using Windows Server 2008 Standard

Tags: workgroup

How to join an established Microsoft Workgroup using Windows Server 2008 Standard? I have Windows Network Wizard on CD, Created by one of the XP systems, but that fails to finish on Server 2008. I get a message to install manually, which I'm happy to do, but where to start?

Answer (score 2):

NetBIOS workgroups do not have a join process other than configuring the *workgroup name* to match (in the 'System' control panel `sysdm.cpl`).

(It's because NetBIOS workgroups don't *do* much; all they do is group computers for "nearby computer" discovery purposes. Unlike domains, workgroups do not allow the computers to automatically share user accounts or anything like that.)